# Thermal Conductivity of a Harmonic Lattice

Tags: greens-functions, correlation-functions, thermal-conductivity, molecular-dynamics

I have been trying to compute the conductivity using the Green-Kubo formula obtained from molecular dynamics simulations. I used a square lattice and a harmonic
potential and I consistently get a decreasing conductivity with temperature. This would be reasonable if unharmonicity were included, in which case increasing
phonon-phonon scattering would result in a decreasing conductivity. For a purely harmonic potential, this seems odd. Indeed, I have also used the Green's function
method for the same system, square lattice and harmonic interactions up to second nearest neighbors, and get an increasing conductivity with temperature.
This result is consistent with earlier published works, such as "Simulation of Phonon Transport Through Graphene with a Green's Function Method" of Huang, Fisher,
and Murthy. I would really appreciate any help as to how to explain these contradicting behaviors of the conductivity when computed from lattice dynamics vs when
computed from molecular dynamics.